# Python versus Matlab on the quantity 1/0

Tags: floating-point, python

Python and Matlab seem to disagree on the division by 0.

Python:

```
>>> 1 / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Matlab:

```
>>> 1 / 0
Inf
```

with the usual properties of $\infty$ for Inf.

Which one is correct when it comes to the IEEE double-precision format?

Comment: Both are allowed behaviors. In python you can use `numpy.float64(1.0)/numpy.float64(0.0)` to get as result `numpy.float64('inf')` and a `RuntimeWarning` instead of the `ZeroDivisionError` exception.

Comment: @plop, can I encourage you to write that as an answer instead of as a comment, so we can upvote it and so the question is marked as answered?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the copy that I have of IEEE 754 (2008) it says

> 7.3 Division by zero 7.3.0
>
> The divideByZero exception shall be signaled if and only if an exact infinite result is defined for an operation on finite operands. The default result of divideByZero shall be an ∞ correctly signed according to the operation:
>
> ― For division, when the divisor is zero and the dividend is a finite non-zero number, the sign of the infinity is the exclusive OR of the operands’ signs (see 6.3).
>
> ― For logB(0) when logBFormat is a floating-point format, the sign of the infinity is minus (−∞).

Python is choosing that the exception that the standard requires is a Python exception. My own interpretation is that this agrees with section 7.3. We don't get the value `float('inf')` because the exception interrupts the execution. I personally find it a bit inconvenient. I don't know the reasons they had for this choice.

One can get the behavior of obtaining a value by using `numpy`. With

```
x = numpy.float64(1.0)/numpy.float64(0.0)
```

we get

```
x = numpy.float64('inf')
```

and a `RuntimeWarning`. Alternatively, one can capture the exception `ZeroDivisionError` and produce the result `float('inf')` ourselves.

In Matlab we get `inf` as the result. It agrees with the standard because I think there is a warning (a flag) that can be seen by setting `warning on MATLAB:divideByZero`.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Matlab gives infinity because it's working directly with floats. IEEE754 floats attempt to let errors propagate through a computation instead of immediately crashing a program when something such as division by zero is encountered.

Python division, whether integer or float (`1/0`, `1.0/0.0`, `1//0`), all have special checks for integer division at the software level ([e.g.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/442ad74fc2928b095760eb89aba93c28eab17f9b/Objects/floatobject.c#L600)).

There's a fundamental problem with integer division by zero: the hardware generates a hardware arithmetic fault that's difficult to recover from. As to why Python doesn't allow float division by zero either, I can only speculate about the design decision. It may be to help the user catch mistakes in computations closer to the sources. To avoid this, you can use a numpy float or alternative which doesn't add this extra check.

Comment: But Python does not work with floats by default then?

Comment: @pluton Thanks, that's an excellent question. I've edited my post to elaborate on the design decisions here.

Comment: Well, in [the same repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/442ad74fc2928b095760eb89aba93c28eab17f9b/Objects/longobject.c#L3810) you can see that Python, interpreted by CPython, generates the exception `ZeroDivisionError` at the software level for `1/0`.

Comment: I think the main reason why the implementation of `/` (what they call true division) needs to go through different pathways for `1/0` and for `1.0/0.0` is that the inputs have different types. In particular, when the operands are integers they can have arbitrary length. For example, if `x=13333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333332` and `y=19999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999998` they still want to return the same `float` as when dividing `2/3` and when dividing `2.0/3.0`.

Comment: @plop Looks like there's also a top-level check for pure int division (`1//0`). I will update my answer to make the distinction about additional checks vs fundamental reasons why int division by zero is not possible.